# How to edit the title page of the beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles

I would like to edit the title page of the beamer presentation template in order display my name and my project supervisor's name in the title slide. Is this possible? Can it be achieved easily?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This can, of course, be done. Which theme are you using?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am using the theme CambridgeUS at the moment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possible solution follows. I adjusted some settings so that now you have a new command `\supervisor` which behaves analogously to `\author` and lets you introduce the supervisor's name below the author's name. The name will be preceded by the string "Supervisor: " which can be changed using `\supervisortitle`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\let\insertsupervisor\relax
\newcommand\supervisortitle{Supervisor}
\mode<all>
{
  \newcommand\supervisor[1]{\def\insertsupervisor{#1}}
  \titlegraphic{}
}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{supdefault}[1][]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\relax%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \ifx\insertsupervisor\relax\relax\else
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\supervisortitle:~\insertsupervisor
    \end{beamercolorbox}\fi
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[supdefault][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]\makeatother

\title{The Title}
\subtitle{The Subtitle}
\author{The Author}
\supervisor{David Hilbert}
\institute{The Institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gonzala Medina Thanks, I appreciate your effort. I will implement this in my presentation right away.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina is it possible to add text "Student: " before the author name? Like you have done for Supervisor.