# Putting more near the \title to the \author and so on

Tags: beamer, frame-title

How I can put the title line closer to the author line and to a title image?

I do not use any theme. I have this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[left,height=0pt,width=0.12\paperwidth]{sidebar}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[vertical shading][top=black,bottom=white] 

\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge,series=\bfseries,parent=structure}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\large,series=\bfseries,parent=structure}

\title[THE BIG TITLE]{THE BIG TITLE}
\author[]{Me}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{IMAGE}}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
%\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: Sorry, how I can do that?

Comment: You just have to copy-paste your code in this edit window, select it  and click on the pair of braces icon in the toolbar.

Comment: see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155677/how-to-edit-the-title-page-of-the-beamer

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[left,height=0pt,width=0.12\paperwidth]{sidebar}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[vertical shading][top=gray,bottom=white] 

\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge,series=\bfseries,parent=structure}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\large,series=\bfseries,parent=structure}

\title[]{THE BIG TITLE}
\author[]{Me}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}}
\date{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
%    \vskip1em\par
        \vskip0em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
%    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
%      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
%    \end{beamercolorbox}
%    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
%      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
%    \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vskip0.5em\par
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]