# how to make a distance in the first page of a presentation

Tags: beamer

I need to consider the following requirements:

1. Changing the institute's size;
2. Placing an email address (small font) at the left side of the first page;
3. Placing the time (smaller font) below the email address.

How can I do that?

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
    \mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    }
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{booktabs} 
    \usepackage[font=Times,timeinterval=10]{tdclock}


    \title[Short title]{my tiltle } 
    \author{my name} 
    \institute[Harvard] 
      {Harvard Med \\ % Your institution for the title page
    \medskip
    \textit{email@hdt.} % Your email address
    }

    \date{\today} 
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage 
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Overview} 
    \tableofcontents 
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please consider a `compilable MWE` including `document class` and preamble.

Comment: Just check [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @Roboticist I got your point. I modified it

Comment: You don't HAVE to use \titlepage.

Comment: see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155686/36296

Comment: To change the fontsize of the institut, you can use `\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\tiny}`.  Can you please clarify what you mean by your other points? Where should an email and time be displayed?

Comment: @samcarter thanks for your message. I want the time to be displayed at the bottom with smaller font and I want email address to be displayed right corner at the Bottom

Comment: @nik In the footline? above the footline? only on the front page? on all pages? which format should the time have? Can you draw a sketch to make things a bit clearer?

Comment: @samcarter I made an example, please look above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way could be to manually add the information after the `\titlepage`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[font=Times,timeinterval=10]{tdclock}

\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\small}

\title[Short title]{my tiltle } 
\author{my name} 
\institute[Harvard]{Harvard Med}

\date[\today]{} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\vskip2cm
\titlepage 
\vskip2cm\tiny\href{mailto:email@hdt}{email@hdt} 
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to make the institute bold ?

Comment: @nik `\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\small, series=\bfseries}`

Comment: I liked and accepted your answer. is it possible to also tell me how to increase the distance between the name and the institute ?

Comment: @nik see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155677/how-to-edit-the-title-page-of-the-beamer/155686#155686